# Multiple Tests running in windows forms simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, forms, selenium

I have a testing application built in windows forms/C# using the Selenium testing suite.  The program works by opening a form with a test object and then executing the test and displaying the results in the form.  All of this works but for scalability purposes I would like to run multiple tests at the same time.  What I have now opens each test in it's own form but once started all of the other forms are locked and will not initiate their tests until the first form is finished.  Is there a way to launch each form on it's own thread so that they can run simultaneously?

I've copied the relevant block that instantiates the different testing forms.  Each form has it's own "start" button to initiate the test...

```
    foreach (ITest test in mastertestlist)
        {
            ResultsForm results = new ResultsForm();
            results.test = test;
            results.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to have multiple UI threads (each Form having their own thread would require this).  It's just a massive headache that will make the program *really* hard to work with.

Instead continue to use a single UI thread, but don't do your actual testing/business work within the UI thread when you click the forms start button.  Have each form ensure that the testing work that it does is performed in a background thread.  One simple way to do this is to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  (There are also a number of other possible techniques.)  You can then use a single UI thread to handle marshalling all UI updates based on the results of the tests, while still doing the long running work in background threads.

Comment: This was excellent.  I'm fairly junior as far as development is concerned but this answer got me on the right path.  I really appreciate your help.